# EntityDataSet fetch all data and then applying where clause

Tags: entity-framework, gridview, asp.net-dynamic-data, entitydatasource

I am using a asp.net GridView control and setting DatasourceId to EntityDataSource as below .in the 
page load setting the GridDataSource.EntityTypeFilter to a View name  and also adding a where clause as GridDataSource.Where = sWhereClause

The View has million records but the Where condition filter out the record .The EntityDataSource first getting all million record in Sub-Query then applying the Where which timing out command. its generating the query as below. I want the where clause shouldgo with ViewName select statement itself not with sub-query table Extent1.

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
[Filter1].[COL1],
[Filter1].[COL2]
[Filter1].[Col3] 
FROM ( 
SELECT [Extent1].[COL1] , [Extent1].[COL2], [Extent1].[COL3]
, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[COL1] ASC
) AS [row_number]

FROM 
(
SELECT 
ViewName.V1 , 
ViewName.V2
ViewName.V3
ViewName.V4

FROM [dbo].ViewName
)
AS [Extent1]


WHERE ([Extent1].[COL1] LIKE '%FilterValue%') 
    OR ([Extent1].[COL1] LIKE '%FilterValue%') OR ([Extent1].[COL2] LIKE '%FilterValue%') OR ([Extent1].[COL3] LIKE '%FilterValue%') )
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].COL1] ASC
```

Thanks and appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The EntityDataSource first getting all million record in Sub-Query then applying the Where which timing out command

Just because the `WHERE` clause is not in the subquery does not mean that subquery isn't filtered.  SQL Server (assuming that's what you're using), can "push down" the `WHERE` clause predicates into the subquery, and into base tables in view definition.

But that won't make any difference here as your multiple `LIKE` predicates have to be evaluated for every single row in the output of the view, then all the rows have to be sorted to find the top 20.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try to refactor and see how it perform.